# CHROOT Post setup activities

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, chroot

After making my working directory as fake root file system,

I had to explicitly mount `/proc` from actual root file system to my fake(temporary) root file system

> sudo mount -o bind /proc /home/abcd/workspace/apolo.0/proc

Without a mount, Doesn't my fake root file system show all the process states that actual root proc file system shows?

Comment: No.  Without binding /chroot/proc to /proc there is no interface the chroot processes can work with.  Now, depending on what you want to do in your chroot you may or may not need to mount it.

Comment: @ivanivan So, Without mount, `/chroot/proc` will show only processes that are launched from `/chroot/proc` directory? `init` process is not one of them, for example

Comment: Do you mean **With** a mount rather than **Without** a mount? Without a mount, of course, `/chroot/proc` will not contain anything at all (unless you manually put something there)...

Comment: @Celada Yes I just checked nothink is in `/chroot/proc`. Am talking **Without** a mount

Comment: @Celada Do I need to also copy `/etc/resolve.conf` to `/CHROOT/etc/resolv.conf`? as post setup activity?

Comment: @overexchange wihtout mounting it, the kernel has no place to create files/directories within the chroot...  You need to put something in /chroot/etc/resolv.conf if you want to use network.  If you have dnsmasq etc running on the "host" you'll need to find out what your nameservers really are, or use google's at 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4

Comment: @overexchange There are many things you need to put in a chroot to make it functional. `/etc/resolv.conf` is not the least of them, but there are many, many more.